# java.util.InputMismatchException error reading file

Tags: java

I know there are a lot of topics with this error but I cannot find any solution to my problem. I am trying to implement a program which reads a file and part of the data is placed into objects, at the same time these are stuck into one array. Each line of the file is one object which I call `Client` or `VIPClient` depending on if the value is true or not. This is the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException: For input string: "1234567890123456"
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2166)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2119)
at javaapplication1.readfile.readFile(readfile.java:31)
at javaapplication1.main.main(main.java:16)
```

and this is the code:

```
public static Client[] readClients(Client[] arraycl){
//arraycl is the empty array where the objects will be placed
        do{
        String name=xclientes.next();
        String dni=xclientes.next(); //dni is id
        int ccnumber=xclientes.nextInt();//the error is here
        int drivingyear=xclientes.nextInt();
        boolean vip=xclientes.nextBoolean(); 
        int vipcard=xclientes.nextInt();
        for (int i=0; i<=arraycl.length ;i++){
            arraycl[i] = new VIPClient(name,dni,ccnumber,drivingyear,0,null,true,vipcard);
            arraycl[i]=new Client(name,dni,ccnumber,drivingyear,0,null,false);
            arraycl[i]=new Client(name,dni,ccnumber,drivingyear,0,null,false);
            arraycl[i]=new Client(name,dni,ccnumber,drivingyear,0,null,false);   
            arraycl[i]= new VIPClient(name,dni,ccnumber,drivingyear,0,null,true,vipcard);
            arraycl[i]= new VIPClient(name,dni,ccnumber,drivingyear,0,null,true,vipcard);
            arraycl[i]=new Client(name,dni,ccnumber,drivingyear,0,null,false);
            arraycl[i]= new Client(name,dni,ccnumber,drivingyear,0,null,false);
            arraycl[i]=new Client(name,dni,ccnumber,drivingyear,0,null,false);
            arraycl[i]= new Client(name,dni,ccnumber,drivingyear,0,null,false);
            closeFile(xclientes);
        }  //end for
        return arraycl;
        } while (xclientes.hasNext());

}//end readClientes
```

The 0 and null values will be set afterwards, so here is the text file:

```
Turing 55550000A 1234567890123456 5 true 1
Knuth 55550001B 0001000000000000 13 false
Wirth 55550010C 0010000000000000 1 false
Dijkstra 55550100D 1100000000000000 2 false
Allen 55551000E 1000000000000000 6 true 2
Curie 55550101M 0101000000000000 3 true 3
Pearl 55550110K 0110000000000000 4 false
Liskov 55551111K 1111000000000000 15 false
Pearl 55550110K 0110000000000000 8 false
Codd 55551110P 1110000000000000 7 false
```

The structure of the file is:

```
name(String) id(String) ccnumber(int) drivinyear(int) vip(boolean) vipcard (int)
```

I think the problem is that netbeans thinks the `ccnumber` is string which obviously isn't (1234567890123456), or maybe the number is too large (probably not) but I have no idea what to do. I tried to make `ccnumber` as a `String` and then parse it but it only gave me more problems. I'd be so grateful if you could give me some advice on how to solve the error.

Comment: MaxValue for int in Java is - `2147483647`, clearly your number is too big.

Comment: But again, I don't think you should be using `int` or `long` for `ccnumber` because you have some entries like `0010000000000000`. If you use `long` then `0010000000000000` will become same as `010000000000000` and `10000000000000`.

Comment: What format should i use then? String?

Comment: Yes... Strings should work just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `int` uses `32` bits thus ranges from -2<sup>31</sup> to 2<sup>31</sup>-1, so the maximum is:

```
maximum bound    2 147 483 648
value    1 234 567 890 123 456
```

So it's clear you can't parse this in an `int`. A `long` has `64` bits so the maximum value is 2<sup>63</sup>-1 or:

```
maximum bound 9 223 372 036 854 775 807
value             1 234 567 890 123 456
```

This is thus withing the bounds and can be represented.

---

Another thing you will have trouble with is that you call:

```
closeFile(xclientes);
```

If this does what I think it does, you are closing the stream before going for a new loop. That will probably cause errors.

In fact you're loop doesn't make much sense at all because it will **overwrite** all data that was originally stored there. Furthermore once you've read a record, you're gonna return. So you will never fetch a second person anyway.

Comment: I've just deleted the closeFile(xclientes); and like you said the program only recognizes the first line of the file. How could i fix the array loop to  read the second line in the file and fetch the second person/object?

Comment: Well first of all: why do you make that many `...Client` instances for each person?

Answer (score 1):

Do not use `nextInt`. Use `nextLong`, because `1234567890123456` is out of Integer range (see `Integer.MIN_VALUE` and `Integer.MAX_VALUE` [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html)).